# Why recycling chron class doesn't work in data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, chron

`data.frame` recycles shorter vectors to match the length of the data frame.

```
test1 = data.frame(x = 1:5, date = as.Date("2013-05-01"))
  x       date
1 1 2013-05-01
2 2 2013-05-01
3 3 2013-05-01
4 4 2013-05-01
5 5 2013-05-01
```

However, it does not seem to work with the `chron` class:

```
require(chron)
test2 = data.frame(x = 1:5, time = times("08:00:00"))

Error in data.frame(x = 1:5, time = times("08:00:00")) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 1
```

There are workarounds, e.g. doing the recycling manually, like:

```
test3 = data.frame(x = 1:5, time = times(rep("08:00:00",5)))
```

But why doesn't the recycling work? Am I missing something here or is there a bug somewhere?

Comment: To do it without making use of the length of `x`: `transform(data.frame(x = 1:5, time = "08:00:00"), time = times(time))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `data.frame` notes:

> Objects passed to data.frame should have the same number of rows, but
>   atomic vectors (see is.vector), factors and character vectors
>   protected by I will be recycled a whole number of times if necessary
>   (including as elements of list arguments).

If you look at the source for `data.frame`, you can actually see the check for `is.vector`.

So the question is, is your `times` object a vector? The answer's no:

```
is.vector(times("8:00:00"))
# [1] FALSE
```

Why is this? `?is.vector` tells us a little more:

> is.vector returns TRUE if x is a vector of the specified mode having
>   no attributes other than names. It returns FALSE otherwise.

If you take a closer look at your `times` object, you can see that it does indeed have a non-names attribute:

```
str(times("8:00:00"))
# Class 'times'  atomic [1:1] 0.333
#  ..- attr(*, "format")= chr "h:m:s"
```

Interestingly, `Date` objects aren't vectors either, but `data.frame` makes an exception.

So, in the end, maybe the recycling *rule* is actually the recycling *exception*, at least in the case of `data.frame`. As you've already figured out though, a workaround is easy enough.